# PKI and code signing

Tags: x509, sign, pki

I have some difficulties to understand the difference between code signing and PKI.
Is it possible to use a PKI (with a hierarchy of CA) to issue certificate used to sign code source, and then use the revocation to invalid some software (for instance an old version that should not be used) ? Or are X.509 certificate incompatible with code signing and i'm missing something ?

Thanks your very much.

Comment: X.509 certificates can be used for code signing, yes. Arguably they are the most common type of certificate for that. And yes, a PKI system behind it is a good idea. It’s up to whoever validates the signature to check the certificate and its revocation.

Answer (score 0):

The PKI is an infrastructure that allows you to issue certificates with which you sign your **binaries** (among other things). You don't sign the source code.

You can create a separate certificate for every software release you have, however, I didn't see anybody use it this way and for that purpose.

Usually you enroll a few certificates and use them to sign all releases until they expire.
Even if a certificate does expire, it won't prevent from the customer keep using your software.